# Naming components in a vector using a for loop

Tags: r, vector, components, naming

I am trying to add vectors to a list in a for loop and want the components to be named according to the value of the counter

This is how I add vectors to the list without the for loop

```
momentum$mom1 <- (prices[period.ends, ] / mlag(prices[period.ends,],1)-1)
momentum$mom3 <- (prices[period.ends, ] / mlag(prices[period.ends,],3)-1)
momentum$mom6 <- (prices[period.ends, ] / mlag(prices[period.ends,],6)-1)
```

but this looks inefficient and there must be a way to create the name "mom1", "mom2" and "mom3" by somehow concatenate-ing "mom" and i (being the counter in a loop that assumes the values 1,3,6).

I was thinking along the lines of

```
momentum = list()
periods <- c(1,3,6)
for (i in periods){
    momentum$paste("mom",i,sep="")<- (prices[period.ends,]/mlag(prices[period.ends,],i)-1)
```

}

Have searched this forum extensively but cant seem to find my answer. I am a beginner in R so your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double square bracket assignment to a list will evaluate its argument:

```
> z=list()
> n="foo"
> z[[n]]=99
> z
$foo
[1] 99
```

So your irreproducible example will be something like:

```
for (i in periods){
    momentum[[paste0("mom",i)]] <- (prices[period.ends,]/mlag(prices[period.ends,],i)-1)
```

alternatively you could construct the list without names, create a vector of names and then assign it to the list using `names(momentum) = paste0("mom",periods)`

Answer (score 2):

```
momentum = list()

periods <- c(1,3,6)

n <- length(periods)
```

Change each name after the list entry has been created:

```
for (i in 1:n){
  momentum[[i]] <- "stuff"
  names(momentum)[i] <- paste("mom",i,sep="")
}
```

Now the object momentum has the required  names